# C++ Stuck in Loop

Tags: c++

```
huffmanFile.open("code.txt");

while(huffmanFile.peek() != EOF)
{
    cin >> letters[c] >> numbers[c];
    c++;
}

huffmanFile.close();
```

Input File:
A   23
B   35
C   47
D   0
E   12
F   11
G   92
H   18
I   17

I try to output c from my main function after executing this and it will not get out of the while loop. I have tried debugging with no avail. I have compared this to numerous other programs I have written and am still having no luck.

Comment: You can move your `cin` part to the loop condition and get rid of what's currently there (and make sure it's the right stream).

Comment: Two different streams are being used: `huffmanFile` and `cin`. `huffmanFile` is _never_ read from so `EOF` will never be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `huffmanFile` is an `istream` object type, you may try using this variant:

```
while (huffmanFile >> letters[c] >> numbers[c]) {
    ++c;
}
```

Explanation:
The [`istream::operator >>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) sets its internal flag called `eofbit` if the end of a stream has been reached. It also returns `*this`, allowing us to perform sequence of readings like `cin >> a >> b >> c`.
After that, an `istream` object is being tested by `while` clause, i.e. the internal [`bool operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) is called, which in turn returns `true` if the `eofbit` flag has been set, `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`cin` is the standard input stream, it usually takes input from the keyboard. You need to read your input from the file instead.

The loop never terminates because the file read position is never getting advanced.